# Rails 3 - Controller/View Subdirectories Routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have some controllers separated out into subdirectories like:

```
app/dept1/user_controller/action
```

With this configuration in the controller:

```
class Dept1::UserController < ApplicationController
end
```

In rails 2, that's all I needed to do and the application was able to auto-route just fine.

But in rails 3, it appears I need to do some routing configurations. I've tried using namespaces:

```
  namespace :dept1 do
    resources :user
  end
```

This page pulls up fine:

```
app/dept1/user_controller/index
```

But app/dept1/user_controller/report returns this error:

```
 "ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/dept1/user/report")"
```

What else do I need to configure?

UPDATE:

When I put this in my routes, it works:

```
namespace :dept1 do
  resources :user do
    collection do
      get :report
      post :report
    end
  end
end
```

Is there a way I can do this without hardcoding each action?

MORE UPDATES:

Here's what I did to fix the routes to work right. It must be in this order:

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :controller => /dept1\/[^\/]+/
match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
```

Answer (score -1):

It's a feature to force you designing your URL RESTful.But if you really want the Rails 2 way, see the last block in config/routes.rb:

```
# This is a legacy wild controller route that's not recommended for RESTful applications.
# Note: This route will make all actions in every controller accessible via GET requests.
# match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
```

The comment says it make GET accessible, indeed it makes all HTTP verbs accessible.

For nested resources, I guess you need to nest the rule above under `namespace :dept1`.

But I still recommend you to use the Rails 3 way, and expose only nessacery interfaces.

Comment: Uncomment the line which acts like a catch all route # match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'